# How do I subscribe to an Observable and use that value in a Javascript Object?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, observable, ionic4

I'm fairly new to Observables, RxJS and Angular in general. I'm using Angular 7 (Ionic 4) and am having a hard time wrapping my head around a solution to the problem below.

In my application, I make an HTTP GET request as follows:

```
myData = this.http.get("https://example.com/api").pipe(
  map(results => {
    return results["payload"]
  })
)
```

This HTTP GET request returns an Observable `myData` which has the following data:

```
const data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "abc",
    "description": "test1" 
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "def",
    "description": "test2" 
  },

  ...

  ...

]
```

I want to add another key `color` to each object in this array like this:

```
const data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "abc",
    "description": "test1",
    "color": "green"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "def",
    "description": "test2",
    "color": "red"
  },

  ...

  ...

]
```

Instead of hard coding the value of `color` for each object, I want to retrieve this key value from a function `getColor(id)` which is in another service called `colorService`.

The problem is that that `colorService.getColor(id)` returns an Observable.

**The question:** How can I subscribe to `colorService.getColor(id)` for each object in my array?

I want to do something like this:

```
const data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "abc",
    "description": "test1",
    "color": <subscribe to colorService.getColor(1)>
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "def",
    "description": "test2",
    "color": <subscribe to colorService.getColor(2)>
  },

  ...

  ...

}
```

I hope I'm clear. My concepts are rather weak at this point, so apologizes if some of it sounds confusing.

Comment: It looks like a chatty client. Does your end point have a way to get all color names (a lookup by id) or multiple colors by id filtered by id? Then you would only need 2 calls (the one you have now plus get color lookup)

Comment: I don't understand why don't you subscribe to `myData` then add the color of each object in a loop, I don't see whats wrong with that

Comment: not sure if this is best way...but https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8mcsxc

Comment: @Igor I done another example using two http calls, is this what you were getting at? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mbbqds

Comment: i was going to post this as an answer but @user2216584 already provided same solution so, for reference here is [my solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fhiqxw)

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. Your solutions helped me understand Observables better. It finally makes sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you can do [See the explanation in the code comments]-

```
myData = this.http.get("https://example.com/api")
                      .pipe(
                              mergeMap(results => {
                                const data = results["payload"];
                                //I am assuming that `data` is the array that you mentioned in your question
                                //Iterate through each of the object in the array and map it to an observable which
                                //will fetch the color and then return the data with color

                                //obs will be an array of observables for each data
                                const obs = data.map(d => {                                  
                                  return this.colorService.getColor(d.id)
                                             .pipe(
                                               map(color => {
                                                 return {...d, color};
                                               })
                                             );
                                });

                                //wait for all the obs to be returned;
                                return forkJoin(obs);
                              }),
                              tap(dataArrayWithColor => {
                                //dataArrayWithColor will have an array of object which will have data with color
                                console.log(dataArrayWithColor);
                              })
                          );
```

Hope it helps.